# Why hibernate creates only first table?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I want to create multiple tables using `createNativeQuery`, but it results in hibernate creating only first table. If I copy paste SQL to SQL editor, it works fine. Here is my code:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE \"languages\"("+
    "language_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"+
    "language_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,"+
    "language_code VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL);"+

    "CREATE TABLE \"accountant\"("+
    "accountant_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"+
    "name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,"+
    "surname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,"+
    "mail VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,"+
    "avatar VARCHAR(150),"+
    "phone VARCHAR(16),"+
    "interface_lang_id INTEGER NOT NULL,"+
    "FOREIGN KEY(interface_lang_id) REFERENCES languages(language_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT);"+

    "CREATE TABLE \"currency\"("+
    "currency_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"+
    "name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,"+
    "symbol VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL);";         
session.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: i'm not sure you can execute DDL (CREATE, ALTER, DROP etc..) with JPA native queries but only DML (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT etc...). For DDL operations you should use `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` as suggested by Sangram Badi

Comment: Actually it's possible to use DDL with JPA native queries, so Sangram Badi solution should work.

Comment: @AbassA , yes i think my solution may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**createNativeQuery()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-) is used for executing a single native SQL statement and not multiple ones in a row.

In your case you are trying to execute 3 differents queries with the same call and that's what's causing it to stop after creating the first table.

If you check the **[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-)** it says:

> **Query createNativeQuery(String sqlString)**
>
> Create an instance of Query for executing a native SQL statement,
> e.g., for update or delete.

**Solution:**

You need to separate these 3 queries in differents `createNativeQuery` calls so they can be interpreted independently.

Answer (score 1):

Split 3 create queries and execute `session.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();` for 3 create queries. You have wrote 3 queries to perform same time. Here `createNativeQuery` method, after executing 1st create statement it's cursor moved to next line of code. so i think this is the problem may happened.

In another way you can automatically create table at server startup time. Create the beans for 3 table put all required annotations in beans. Then change hibernate.cfg.xml file as `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` then tables will create at the time of server startup time